# C++ const char* array 2 variables into one 'cell'?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have a text file with 1000 hex values in it like this:

```
00 2f 3a 2e...
```

and I'm trying to store them in a const char* array with both values in each 'cell', like '00' '2f' '3a'.

Currently, each 'cell' is only containing one character '0' '0' '2' 'f' '3' 'a'.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
void Myfunction::Myfile(const char* fileName)
    {

    ifstream Myfile(fileName);

    if (Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!Myfile.eof() && i < 1000)
            {
              Myfile >> Array[i];
              i++;
            }
    }
    Myfile.close();
}
```

I've looked at dynamic memory allocation, pairs, typecasting and just haven't found a solution that fits. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of `Array` and the error messages that you're getting?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert `2f` to the character value `0x2F` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your array is of 'char', you can only write a single character to each element.  The first character is a '0', the second is a '0', the third is a ' ', and so on.

If you want to treat the words of your input as integers and store one of those integers in each element of your array, then you'll need to read them in as strings and convert them to integers.  Boost's lexical_cast (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) might help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` array is an array of `char`s; by definition, each "cell" can only hold a single `char`.

You could, if you computed what number each hex value represents, store *that* value in a `char` (or, more appropriately, an `unsigned char`).  Or, if you insist on storing 2 `char`s for each value, declare an array whose "cells" can each hold 2 `char`s.

Answer (score 0):

A sort of ANSI C solution would be to make a data structure:

```
typedef struct _hex_val{
   char first;
   char second;    
}t_hex_val;
```

Then you would allocate a large pointer to this and fill it up. You would need a little bit of parsing code to find the `' '` values between the pairs of chars.

I realize that his is very against the grain of what C++ can do, but sometimes, simple C is the easiest (at least for me).